# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am using Vuexy Dashboard in my project, Vuexy comes in with Vue 2, so I am trying to upgrade it to Vue 3, after fixing some errors, I'm stuck on this one, any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.
This is my package.json file :

```
 {
  "name": "vuexy-vuejs-react-html-laravel-admin-dashboard-template",
  "version": "6.4.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "4.1.6",
    "@casl/vue": "1.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.1.0-0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.6.1",
    "@vueuse/core": "4.0.0",
    "animate.css": "4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.2",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "core-js": "3.8.1",
    "echarts": "4.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "leaflet": "1.6.0",
    "portal-vue": "2.1.7",
    "postcss-rtl": "1.7.3",
    "prismjs": "^1.28.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "swiper": "5.4.5",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "0.2.1",
    "vue-prism-component": "1.1.1",
    "vue-quill-editor": "3.0.6",
    "vue-ripple-directive": "2.0.1",
    "vue-router": "3.4.9",
    "vue-select": "3.11.2",
    "vue-slider-component": "3.2.11",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "4.1.1",
    "vue-toastification": "1.7.8",
    "vue-tour": "1.5.0",
    "vue-tree-halower": "1.8.3",
    "vue2-leaflet": "2.5.2",
    "vuedraggable": "2.24.3",
    "vuex": "3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.0-0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "@vuepress/plugin-medium-zoom": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.1.1",
    "sass": "1.32.*",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0"
  }
}
```

And these are the errors I'm getting while running npm run serve :

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/nonIterableSpread.js 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js' in 'Desktop\consigliere-vue-laravel\e-commerce\frontend\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\esm'
```

Comment: Make sure you freshly installed deps and check with your eyes that node_modules/core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js and/or node_modules\@babel\runtime/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js  exist

Comment: I just checked, and unfortunately, both do not exist, what to do in this case?

Comment: Install the dependencies. There is core-js in deps, the only reason for it to not exist in node_modules is that you didn't install them correctly

Comment: I tried deleting the node_modules folder and then running npm install, but still, the same error.

Answer (score 19):

After searching a lot, what works for me was what I found in this blog post:

https://blog.csdn.net/Missbelover/article/details/123221351

Basically, what you need to do is...

1. Remove all your `node_modules` dependencies.

```
npm rm -rf node_modules
```

2. Install `core-js` first.

```
npm install --save core-js
```

3. Finally install everything else.

```
npm install
yarn install
```

After this everything should work as expected, a least for me is working now.

Have a good day!

Comment: for pure `yarn` users, step 1: `rm -rf node_modules`. step 2: `yarn add core-js`. step 3 `yarn serve/dev/<your script>`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was having 2 projects that differ because they use yarn and npm. I made the mistake of installing jest globally with yarn so had conflicts with my jest version. I ran `yarn remove global jest` and it worked.